# How to share a link with image on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta-tags

I'm trying to make link button that shares the page on facebook, I'm using that url from facebook https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=. The problem is the page I want to share has a dynamic image, so depending on the parameters in my url the image should be different, for example events.com?id=2, this should bring an image related to event 2 and so on, so I can't put the meta tag on my head. I was trying to add the meta tag after I receive the data from my database using jquery but it doesn't work. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `meta` tags to your page. More info in the [following documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/)

Comment: but I can't put a fixed meta because the path/url of my image comes from the database

Comment: If it comes from the database then you must be using a backend language like php, nodejs, python etc.. which means y9u can put dynamic url

Comment: actually I'm using java script and firebase  $("meta[property='og:image']").attr("content",event.val().url);    
$("head").prepend(`<link rel="image_src" href="${evento.val().caminho}">`)

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the problem. Unfortunately I think you need server side rendering

Comment: I tried to change the attribute and use append and prepend to add the content after receiving from database but I guess facebook reads my file without executing so when it searchs for the meta tag it doesn't exist or it's empty

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: If I were you, I would create an api that renders static html of the shared page and share that link. When the user visits it, redirect him to the dynamic application.